# how to check if an ImageView is attached with image in android

Tags: android

I am setting an image to ImageView in android code not in xml, but could not make out how to check whether that image has been set in or not in java.

Tried with `imageViewOne.getVisibility() == 0` 
but it is not working

If image has been set to ImageView then I am attaching that image for sending mail.

Answer (score 175, accepted):

> imageViewOne.getVisibility() == 0

use this instead:

```
imageViewOne.getDrawable() == null
```

From documentation:

> /**
> * Gets the current Drawable, or null if no Drawable has been
> * assigned.
> *
> * @return the view's drawable, or null if no drawable has been
> * assigned.
> *
> */
> public Drawable getDrawable() {
>
> }

Comment: Lead me to the solution for Xamarin.Android : `imagView.Drawable == null`

Comment: It will not work if an ImageView has placeholder img

Comment: Kotlin: `imageView.drawable == null`

Answer (score 52):

Note that if you set an image via `ImageView.setImageBitmap(BITMAP)`it internally creates a new `BitmapDrawable`even if you pass `null`. In that case the check `imageViewOne.getDrawable() == null`is false anytime. To get to know if an image is set you can do the following:

```
private boolean hasImage(@NonNull ImageView view) {
     Drawable drawable = view.getDrawable();
     boolean hasImage = (drawable != null);

     if (hasImage && (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)) {
         hasImage = ((BitmapDrawable)drawable).getBitmap() != null;
     }

     return hasImage;
}
```

Comment: This is the most complete answer. So remember also if one wants to remove the drawable completely from the ImageView, it is better to setImageDrawable(null) than setImageBitmap(null). If you do this consistently you can rely on getDrawable() to return null.

Comment: @Martin_G you nailed it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thank you the solution.

Answer (score 5):

The correct way to check if the ImageView is attached with the image is:

```
 if (imageView.getDrawable() == null){
       //Image doesn´t exist.
   }else{
        //Image Exists!.
 }
```

Some methods to load images into the ImageView like using Glide or Picasso have a little delay so we must wait for some milliseconds to check:

```
    //Load Image.
    Glide.with(this)
            .load(imageURL)
            .into(imageView);

   //Wait for 500 ms then check!.
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           if (imageView.getDrawable() == null){
              //Image doesn´t exist.
           }else{
              //Image Exists!.
           }
        }
    }, 500
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

if (myImage.getDrawable() == null){

//The imageView is empty

} else{ 


// The imageView is occupied.

}
```

or

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

if ( null == myImage.getDrawable()){

//The imageView is empty

} else{ 


// The imageView is occupied.

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do imageViewOne.getDrawable() for the image you set on the src attribute - meaning setImageResource/Bitmap.
Or imageViewOne.getBackground() for the background attribute - meaning setBackground.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this when any drawable is in your imageview and after you are adding image from gallery or any where. Try This

```
(imgAdd.drawable.constantState == resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.user_new).constantState) -> {
                    Snackbar.make(view, "Please Add Product Image",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin Android `imageViewOne.Drawable == null`

Answer (score -5):

```
if (img_like.getTag() != null && img_like.getTag().toString().equals("red")) {
    img_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.heart);
    img_like.setTag("heart");
} else {
    img_like.setImageResource(R.drawable.red);
    img_like.setTag("red");
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?