# What is quick way to check if ImageView has bitmap assigned?

Tags: android

I need to quickly and safely check if an android.widget.ImageView currently has a Bitmap of non zero value attached.  What is a quick way to do this.

Update my image view is set initially drawable set to "logo.png" so if I know that it is currently set to logo.png than I know that the bitmap has not yet been set.  So how can I check if background drawable is currently logo.png

Thanks

Comment: May be this can help 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113895/how-to-check-if-an-imageview-is-attcahed-with-image-in-android

Comment: I can't accept your comments, only actual answers.

Answer (score 12):

Use getDrawable() method, if it return null then nothing assigned

```
if( mImageView.getDrawable() != null){

  //Image Assigned

}else{
  //nothing assigned

}
```

Comment: In the queston, he mentioned the imageview is already attached with default "logo.png".  If you use your method. It will not return null.  since "logo.png" is there already!!

Comment: I have another situation here, where I have a background color set. The same, getDrawable does not return null even though no src is set.

Answer (score 1):

Assign `ImageView` to variable in `onCreate`:

```
someImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
```

Then a simple if-else statement:

```
Bitmap bm = ((BitmapDrawable) someImage.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

                boolean hasDrawable = (bm != null);
                if(hasDrawable) 
                {
                    hasImage();
                }
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(AppSettings.this, "No Bitmap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Extension Solution:

Add this to simplify checks and make it more readable

```
fun ImageView.hasDrawable() = drawable != null
```

and then call

```
myView.hasDrawable()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Get Bitmap attached to ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306623/get-bitmap-attached-to-imageview)

Check this out.

It looks like you have to create a bitmap from the `ImageView` and check to see if it is `null`.

```
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);    
imageView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageView.getDrawingCache());
imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Ok.  How can I check quickly if my image still has src="logo.jpg" or a bitmap that I set later.  I need to do this really fast.  Is there a way to check if the current background image is logo.jpg?

Comment: I am also looking for the answer..The same scenario I have