# How to tell if ImageView has a set image in android?

Tags: java, android, image

In android, if you create an imageview in the xml code like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture_avatar"
    android:layout_width="90dp" 
    android:layout_height="110dp"
    android:background="#bdbdbd" />
```

How can you tell in the java code, if it has a set image?

There is another button that sets an image using the `setImageBitmap` function. So I want to tell if it has an image or not.

Thanks

Comment: **`There are two more queries similar to this in StackOverflow ... Have a look ... it might help !`** - ***http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9706885/how-can-i-check-if-imageview-is-empty-or-not*** - ***http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9113895/how-to-check-if-an-imageview-is-attcahed-with-image-in-android***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pictureavatar.getDrawable() == null
```

If true, then no image else it has an image